I'm trying to get my old buckets, but keeps giving me a 400 error
I am trying to find a bucket that i used to upload a few revit files, so that i can download them.
The files are there, I know, because I can see them in the viewer.
I am using my credentials, getting my access_token.
But when I create a request like the one below
bucket_url = 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets'
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'text/json'
    }

    bucket_response = requests.post(bucket_url, headers=headers)

I get the message :
bucketss_list_response <Response [400]>
{'reason': 'Unable to parse JSON'}
What am I doing wrong?!
this is how I am getting my access_token:
auth_data = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'scope': 'data:read data:write bucket:create bucket:read'
    }
    newBasicAuth = FORGE_CLIENT_ID+":"+FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET
    encoded = base64.b64encode(newBasicAuth.encode())
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    headers["Authorization"]="Basic " + encoded.decode("utf-8")

    auth_response = requests.post(auth_url, data=auth_data, headers=headers)
    access_token = auth_response.json().get('access_token')

I tried:
curl -X GET "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/YOUR_BUCKET_KEY/objects" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"


And was expecting:
{
  "items": [
    {
      "objectKey": "model_1.rvt",
      "size": 1234567,
      "contentType": "application/octet-stream"
    },
    {
      "objectKey": "model_2.rvt",
      "size": 2345678,
      "contentType": "application/octet-stream"
    }
  ]
}


Here is the process to create and get buckets
Step 1. Get the 2legged token using the curl code below
curl --location 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=account:read account:write data:read data:write bucket:read bucket:create'

Step 2. Create the bucket
curl --location 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'x-ads-region: US' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlhrUFpfoXzlTYzNZS01oRERBZFBWeFowOF9SUzI1NiIsInBpLmF0bSI6ImFzc2MifQ' \
--data '
  {
    "bucketKey":"testbucket",
    "policyKey":"persistent"
  }
  '

Step 3. Get the buckets
curl --location 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets?region=US&limit=100&startAt=1' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlhrUFpfoXzlTYzNZS01oRERBZFBWeFowOF9SUzI1NiIsInBpLmF0bSI6ImFzc2MifQ'

